# Looping and splitting JSON array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I keep getting the error: **undefined is not a function.**

I have a JSON array which I want to loop through, split, and push it to a new array.

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {

  var items = [];

  for (var key in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      items.push(data[key].split(","));
    }
  }
});
```

The JSON I'm working with is http://hawttrends.appspot.com/api/terms/

```
{"42": ["Stefan L\u00f6fven", "Andreas Fransson", "Olympiakos", "Malm\u00f6 FF", "SHL", "Bonde S\u00f6ker Fru 2014", "MFF", "Magnus Uggla", "Anders Eklund", "Ludogorets", "Blondinbella", "Champions League", "Windows 10", "Jagad av hundar", "Gunilla Persson", "Lady Gaga", "Shadow of Mordor", "Dessertm\u00e4starna", "Bj\u00f6rn S\u00f6der", "GoPro Hero 4"]}
```

I don't have much experience with Javascript / jQuery so I'm a little unsure on how best to do this.

Comment: Presumably `data[key]` isn't an object with a `split` method on it. Try looking at the data you're actually dealing with.

Comment: Can you please post some example JSON with the same structure as the `data` being returned in the call?

Comment: How is your json object composed...can you post the output of `console.log(data);`

Comment: why do you need to split, that object property IS the array you're after. just assign it     `items = data["42"];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to get an array of names?

`items` and `data[key]` are both arrays, try this:

```
if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    items = items.concat(data[key]);
}
```

Comment: You're absolutely right, I was looking at this completely the wrong way. It didn't dawn on me to merge the arrays. Works beautifully with my most frequent words count function too. Thanks Christophe.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're misunderstanding the structure of the response here. You receive an object with different keys each containing one array, however there's no `array.split()` function in JavaScript. What you might want to use is

```
for (var key in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      items.push(data[key]);
    }
}
```

which should add all the arrays to `items` resulting in an array of arrays.